# Python read in line of text file into list separated by #

Tags: python-3.x, list, search, split, text-files

I am trying to read in a text file using python to store values in a list. There are two sets of data that I want read in to separate lists separated by a commented out line. The number of lines in each list can vary depending on what the user inputs (example below). So I want to have list1 contain the first two uncommented lines and list2 to contain the third uncommented line. Part of the code I tried is also below but it puts all of the uncommented lines into list 1 (i.e. the logic isn't there to stop adding to list when it sees a "#"). Thanks for any help!

#User input 1#
1 0.5 0.25 0.5
2 0.1 0.1 0.5

#User input 2#
1 1.5 2.0 3.5

```
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for line in Data:
        line = line.rstrip

        if re.search("User input 1"):
            list1 = dict()
            list1['Num'] = []
            list1['x'] = []
            list1['y'] = []
            list1['z'] = []
        
        sp = line.split()
        list1['Num'].append(sp[0])
        list1['x'].append(float(sp[1]))
        list1['y'].append(float(sp[2]))
        list1['z'].append(float(sp[3]))
```

Comment: can you please explain further? with proper formatting of input text i think there's something missing.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide a sample of contents of the variable  Data

Comment: Hi, just go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get started with asking awesome questions, the SO way.